# Is using SheetJS free for commercial use?

Tags: licensing, commercial, law, software, terms-of-service

I downloaded a version of SheetJS here https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.17.4/dist/xlsx.full.min.js

It's basically a version of xlsx that allows me to export an excel document and allows me to manipulate data from the export excel. I'm using this software for commercial purposes and am implementing it in a project. I'm using the community version.

I have the licensing agreement, however I'm not really that legal savvy to understand if I'm able to use the software or not. This is the link to the license : https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the widely-used Apache License 2.0, which allows you to redistribute the work, whether modified or unmodified, for any purpose, as long as you preserve the original author's copyright notices.

One existing Q&A on complying with this license is [Requirements for using an Apache-licensed library](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/requirements-for-using-an-apache-licensed-library)

Comment: What do you mean by preserve the original author's copyright notices? Do I add a comment in the js file and state that this is software by SheetJS?

Comment: @WattMonki, no it is the reverse. You cannot remove such comments from the js file you copied.